# Ajax post works once then works again but not asynchronously

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

What i'm trying to do is simply post the forum asynchronously to a php page and return what it echos to a particular id.

When I first submit, everything works as expected. The text gets sent to the append.php and returns the new list of items promptly without refreshing the page.

The second time I submit text, it seems like it's ignoring the ajax stuff. Instead, it takes me to append.php and displays just the list. Though it still submits the form and adds to the array. This makes me suspect that my problem lies within the script.

***So my question is, what do I need to do for my form to continuously work using AJAX more than once?***

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>For Testing Ajax</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){

                // Bind to the submit event
                $(".ajax").submit(function(event){
                    // Get local variables
                    var form = $(this);
                    // Get inputs of this form
                    var inputs = form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
                    // Get the data to post
                    var serializedData = form.serialize();
                    // prevent additional requests during the duration of this one
                    inputs.prop("disabled", true);

                    // Make the request to the form's ACTION property
                    var request = $.ajax({
                        url: form.prop("action"),
                        type: "post",
                        data: serializedData

                    }).done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
                        // Success
                        console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
                        // Return response to the ID according to the form's NAME property
                        $("#"+form.prop("name")).html(response);

                    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        // Failure
                        console.error(
                            "The following error occured: "+
                            textStatus, errorThrown
                        );

                    }).always(function () {
                        inputs.prop("disabled", false);
                        form.unbind('submit');

                    });

                    event.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>You're on the main page.</h1>
        <div id="list">
            <form class="ajax" method="POST" name="list" action="append.php">
                <input type="text" name="text">
                <input type="submit" value="Append">
            </form>
            <?

            $list = json_decode(file_get_contents('list.json'),true);

            echo '<ul>';
            foreach($list as $item){
                echo '<li>'.$item.'</li>';
            }
            echo '</ul>';

            ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**append.php**

```
<?

// Get the POST stuff
$text = $_POST['text'];

Check if anything was indeed submitted
if (isset($_POST['text'])) {
    // Get current array
    $list = json_decode(file_get_contents('list.json'),true);

    // Add to the array
    $list[] = $text;

    // Save changes to the file
    file_put_contents('list.json',json_encode($list));

    // Return the forum and the array in an unorganized list
    echo '
        <form class="ajax" method="POST" name="list" action="append.php">
            <input type="text" name="text">
            <input type="submit" value="Append">
        </form>
        <ul>';
    foreach($list as $item){
        echo '<li>'.$item.'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

?>
```

Thank you for your time!

PS: I am using jQuery v2.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets see, you have a form inside a DIV

```
<div id="list">
    <form class="ajax" method="POST" name="list" action="append.php">
```

and in the success callback you do

```
$("#"+form.prop("name")).html(response);
```

As the name of the form is `list`, you're effectively replacing everything inside the DIV with the id `#list` with whatever the ajax call returns, and the element you inititally bound the event handler to is gone!

To solve it, use a delegated event handler that works with the new form you put in there as well

```
$(document).on("submit", ".ajax", function(event){
     // your code here
});
```

You're also unbinding the event in the `always` handler, but that doesn't really matter as the form is no longer there after the ajax call is successful.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know it would unbind when the element was gone just for a moment. It works excellently now, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `form.unbind('submit');` it is unbinding your event handler so it doesn't execute the next time.